# Encrypt or Hashing a password

Tags: php, ssh

I have a situation not very commom, or very commom for someone. I need to store some passwords in the database.
Let me explain what I really need.

I have some servers that I need to access 3 times a day, every day, all over the year, is a kind of non-stop service, the SSH service is running in each one of them, and also I have my software that request access to each one of the server 3 times a day. 
Well everything works just fine as I wish, the problem is, PASSWORDS! How to manage all passwords!

Today I have all servers passwords in the script (the same script that actually run the SSH services), since I'm using SSH2 PHP Functions `ssh2_auth_password()` to authenticate to the servers, but it is plain text.

what about this function `ssh2_ auth_ pubkey_ file()` ? How should I use this?

Is it safe, store the password in my own scripts? I do not think so..

Then what to do in this case? If I store the password in the database, I will need to retrieve password on each server request (it is running by cron), then if it is a hash I can compare with a another hash in my script and return a plain text for my function authenticate, still plain text.. (but I think it is not a good solution yet!).

EnCrypt the passwords then DeCrypt the passwords every server request?? maybe possible..

Does someone have any idea what is the best to do in this situation?

I'm in a pool!

Thanks in advance for any light!

**[EDITED]**

My Arch is Kernel Linux 2.6 most of them, 
SaaS application running on a external (neutral server) and 
CronJobs are regurlary running 3 times/day everything is auto by command line, no human interaction.

**[EDITED ONCE MORE]**

Where should I generate the keypair(s) ? Is only one keypair enough for all my servers include the SaaS APP server ? or do I need to generate one by one?
 A bit confused ..

```
                CRON JOBS (fire servers) 3x/day
              ------------
              | SaaS APP |________________________
      ________------------_______                |
     |             |             |               |
     |             |             |               |
-----------   -----------   -----------          |
| SERVER1 |   | SERVER2 |   | SERVER3 |  ....  SERVER4 ....
-----------   -----------   -----------
```

Thanks Again!

Comment: "I'm in a pool!" I read that and immediately pictured Old Spice Guy asking the question.

Comment: Don't use passwords, use public/private key authentication.

Comment: If your script is not accessible externally (and it shouldn't be, and should not be under the wwwroot), then your passwords are "safe"; of course you have to be sure that no one can gain higher privileges on your web server (but that has to be done all the same).

Comment: Either way, you're going to have sensitive data stored in your application somewhere. If you're going to use a properly-secured private key, you'll need to store the key passphrase in your application in order to unlock the private key.

Comment: @tandu, please don't edit questions unless you're making constructive changes.

Comment: @Justin I like this approuch. How should I do this?

Comment: Where is my "I'm in a pool!" ???

Comment: Fernando, can you give us some more detail on the architecture of the system? As I understand it: You have *servers* that you access via ssh and you have *clients* running your PHP code. Is the client-side PHP code being run via cron, manually via command-line, or through a browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6049/discussion-between-fernando-costa-and-jui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with [`ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php).

1. Generate a public/private keypair via `ssh-keygen`.
2. Add the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on each server.
3. Copy the public and private keys to your client machines and make them readable only by the account(s) that need to use them.
4. Change your authentication code in the client to something like this:

   ```
   $ssh_conn = ssh2_connect('my.server.addr', 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));
   if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(
      $ssh_conn,
      'sshuser',
      '/path/to/id_rsa.pub',
      '/path/to/id_rsa',
      'key_passphrase'
   )) {
      echo "Success";
   } else {
      echo "Failure";
   }
   ```

Comment: I think this is the way, but what happen if the admin changes with frequency the server password? Should I generate again the key pair? Thanks

Comment: Once you have this method working, the password on the server is irrelevant. The client uses the private key to prove to the server that he is who he says he is. This takes the place of the password in the authentication process. Your admin could change the server password every 5 seconds and it would still work.

Comment: Wow great! That's the answer I wanted to hear. This is definitely the method. I will try it right now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing intra server communication, via ssh, then definetly use publickeys. If you are simply using password based authentication, the password can be snatched if the target server is compromised or the SSL tunner is cracked. The problem is, you have to each time give the password (well, you can use passwordless pubkeys, but better not). To overcome this difficulty, you could use public keys and an ssh agent which stores your auth passwords, so you only have to type those passwords only once per reboot.

[Pubkey auth tutorial for debian](http://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-ssh-with-public-key-authentication-debian-etch)

Comment: Eh?  If you can use just public keys, why in the world wouldn't you? More secure than a mixed approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your password encrypted in database/file using `mcrypt_encrypt` PHP function and before every connect automatically decrypt this password. Of course you need another password to encrypt your SSH passwords, this one could be stored in another file or, as mentioned before, promt for this password after every reboot and store it only in memory.

Example:

```
<?php
$output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, $key, $plaintextPassword, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
//encode to base64 for easier manipulation
$stored = base64_encode($output);
...
$b64encoded = base64_decode($encryptedPassword);
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, $key, $b64encoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)
?>
```

Comment: I'm in the middle of a crossroads right now, by one side I have the possibilities that my server passwords need to change very often, and by another side if the passwords really changes often I think the best approuch is EnCrypt the password and store it in a database, just like you suppose in your answer. Thanks!